# Optaplanner Drools performance is rather slow

Tags: drools, optaplanner

For maintainability, readability and easy of use I have rewritten our score calculators to Drools and I find that it performs only marginally better than our `EasyScoreCalculator` and is significantly slower than our `IncrementalScoreCalculator`. (The main reason of switching to Drools is failing to implement a new rule in the `IncrementalScoreCalculator`).

Here is a comparison:

[image: Score speed comparisons]

Note that Drools is only marginally faster than Easy and that Incremental is ~8-10 times faster than either.

We have quite a few rules and note that while some rules are about as fast or faster than Incremental some are really slow and likely form a bottleneck.

Here is an example of a fast rule (~18-20 k calcs/sec)

```
rule "The volume of all orders can't exceed the volume of the van"
    when $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity : capacity)
      accumulate(
        Customer(
          vehicle == $vehicle,
          $demand : demand);
        $demandTotal: sum($demand);
        $demandTotal > $capacity
      )
    then
      scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 2, -Math.round($demandTotal - $capacity));
end
```

Here is an example of a really slow rule (~1k calcs/sec)

```
rule "A shipment cannot be serviced outside of the shift's service hours"
  when
    $c: TimeWindowedCustomer( vehicle != null, this.isServicable() == true);
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, -1);
end
```

And another example of a really slow rule:

```
rule "Total used volume in future shifts"
  when
    $shift: Shift(isCurrent() == false)
    $vehicle: TimeWindowedVehicle($shift == shift, $capacity: capacity)
    accumulate(
      Customer(
         vehicle == $vehicle,
         $demand : demand);
      $demandTotal: sum($demand);
      $demandTotal > 0
    )
  then
    int utilisedFutureShiftVolumePenalty = Params.App.Solver.Scoring.utilisedFutureShiftVolumePenalty;
    long score = - utilisedFutureShiftVolumePenalty * Math.round($demandTotal);
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, score);
end
```

I understand that these slow rules form a bottleneck and slow the entire drools score calculation down but I can't figure out why these rules are a bottleneck. The only thing I can think of is that I call a method in the slow rules whereas in the fast ones I don't.

Is this a reason as to why a rule that calls an object method is much slower as otherwise? If yes, why and what should I do about it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What does `isServicable()` do? It probably does far more than just `return servicable;`.

As for the second slow rule, it's an accumulate on the cross product of `Shift` and `Vehicle`. Accumulates are a bit slow (not as slow as `insertLogical`, but still).

It will be interesting to see how **ConstraintStreams** affect these performance benchmarks, once we release them.

Comment: `isServicable()` does a boolean check `return dueTime <= customer.getReadyTime() || readyTime +  MILLIS_PER_HOUR >= customer.getDueTime();` I have tried putting it in rule (though I prefer not to) but performance wise it didn't make a difference. Regarding the second slow rule, it is indeed a cross product of `Shift` and `Vehicle`, but there is only 1 entity of `Shift` that is `isCurrent()==true`, so I am thinking it shouldn't be any different than the first fast rule, performance wise. Unless it does a recalc after every step on all the customers in a shift (about 400 entities) (1/2)

Comment: whereas the first one doesn't. (About 14-15 customers per vehicle) Is this right ? (2/2)

Comment: That's weird on both cases then. That `isServicable()` impl is fine, it doesn't do loops, so it should be fast. And if there is indeed one shift instance, that cross product shouldn't cause a perf impact. At this point, only a deep code review and some extensive benchmarking could help (which me and my collegue's only do through Red Hat services), but all in all, 3k per second isn't bad.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!